# Change stream file names on the go in gulp-watch task

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Even though it is not that necessary I want to have my dev-environment as clean as possible and therefore automatically remove deleted files from my build directory.

Since I'm using TypeScript I want to have the compiled and static files in one directory on the fly. I'm achieving this with watching static files and copying them to a build folder (I probably should rename that in the future).

Deleted files should then also be removed from the build directory. I tried this and almost succeeded. **The only thing I'm trying to find out is how to change a stream file name from `app/tmp.html` to `build/app/tmp.html`**.

This is my watch-task so far:

```
let gulp = require( 'gulp' );
let watch = require( 'gulp-watch' );
let filter = require( 'gulp-filter' );
let clean = require( 'gulp-clean' );

gulp.task( 'watch', function() {
  let deletedFilter = filter( file => {
    return file.event !== 'unlink' && file.event !== 'deleted';
  }, { restore: true } );

  let newFilter = filter( file => {
    return file.event !== 'add';
  } );

  watch( './app/**/*.{html,css,js,map,svg,png,jpg}' )
    .pipe( deletedFilter )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( './build/app/' ) )
    .pipe( newFilter )
    .pipe( deletedFilter.restore ) // this line here
    .pipe( clean() );              // and that line there still make
                                   // some trouble
} );
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was taking a little break and dug into a little deeper. Looking at `gulp-debug` I came up with a solution, using the following, additional node modules to `gulp` and `gulp-watch`:

- **`gulp-filter`** to filter out deleted files in the first place
- **`through2`** to go through all filtered (deleted) files
- **`path`** to get the relative path
- **`gulp-clean`** to actually remove the files from the build directory

All together it looks something like this *(as of writing this answer, I'm using NodeJS 5.10.1)*:

```
'use strict';

let staticFilePattern = `./app/**/*.{html,css,js,map,svg,png,jpg}`;
let buildDirectory = 'build';

let gulp = require( 'gulp' );
let watch = require( 'gulp-watch' );
let filter = require( 'gulp-filter' );
let clean = require( 'gulp-clean' );
let through = require( 'through2' );
let path = require( 'path' );

let changeToBuildDirectory = function() {
  return through.obj( function( file, enc, cb ) {
    file.path = process.cwd() + `/${buildDirectory}/` + path.relative( process.cwd(), file.path );
    cb( null, file );
  });
};

gulp.task( 'watch', function() {
  let deletedFilter = filter( file => {
    return file.event !== 'unlink' && file.event !== 'deleted';
  }, { restore: true } );

  let newFilter = filter( file => {
    return file.event !== 'add';
  } );

  watch( staticFilePattern )
    .pipe( deletedFilter )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( `./${buildDirectory}/app/` ) )
    .pipe( newFilter )
    .pipe( debug( { title: 'Foo' } ) )
    .pipe( deletedFilter.restore )
    .pipe( changeToBuildDirectory() )
    .pipe( clean() );
} );
```

I don't find it very clean, since I'm just modifying the path on the file object, but it works, so I'm pleased. If you got a more clean solution, you are welcome to post another answer or leave it in the comments

I hope it is useful to some extend.
Cheers!